How to change album name using taglib in c#?
I want to change the album name for wav files, but it doesn't work and i don't know why. :(
public void ChangeMetadata()
{
    string artistName = ArtistNameTB.Text;
    string destinationPath = DestinationPathTB.Text;
    string albumName = AlbumNameTB.Text;

    foreach (string file in FolderPathTab)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileName);

        System.IO.File.Copy(file, destinationFilePath, true);

        using (var tagLibFile = TagLib.File.Create(destinationFilePath))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ArtistNameTB.Text) || ArtistNameTB.Text != "")
            {
                tagLibFile.Tag.AlbumArtists = new[] { artistName };
            }
            tagLibFile.Tag.Album = albumName;
            tagLibFile.Save();
        }
    }

I've already searched the internet for a solution but couldn't find one.
